# empty div on right side my content div taking 100% of height space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an empty div on the right side of my content div. This div is empty because I'll use it to put a background image.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/V9XtN/3/

I want that the div bellow take all available space, on the left side of the blue div.

```
#ConteudoDireito {
width: 35%;
height: 100%; 
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: Red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: add `position:absolute;` and `right:0;` to `#ConteudoDireito` :

http://jsfiddle.net/V9XtN/6/

If you later fill the div with content, there is no need for this, since the div will expand to the content height, so you can change it back to what you have now.

Comment: Doing that doesn't really put it `on the left side of the blue div`. It would always float on the right side of the page.

Comment: it's kind of confusing, though, since the div is called ConteudoDireito, which means RightContent

Comment: Yes. right content (ConteudoDireito) should be on the right of left content (ConteudoEsquerdo)

Comment: you can delete the height:100% form left div and nothing changes... actually the div content gives the size of the left div and the right one resizes accordingly because of its absolute position. all those height 100% in the code are useless (but those with position:absolute as in your example)

Comment: The problem here seems to be it would be more correct with a float:left position so that it sticks on the side of left div (even if actually that doesn't really change much). But to afford a float:left a fixed px height is needed somewhere...

Comment: This works for my purpose. But I want to know how to build the solutions without the use of absolute, If it's possible.

Comment: fixed px height could work, but if the left content height changes, then you have to change the hardcoded right div height

Comment: @Ronaldo the absolute position solution is probably the best solution in this situation, but you may think at the final result you want to accomplish and maybe explain it to us so we can figure out the cleanest way to accomplish that.

Comment: For now, I 'm going to use the absolute position. I just want to put a background image with size property setted to contain. I will do some tests and If I had any problem I put another question. Thank you everybody.